# Third party cookies - does secure, httponly matter?

Tags: cookies

Was viewing [this page](https://www.redmaplecoaching.com/cookie-policy) on cookies and wondering for those under Third party cookies, such as TS*, TS01*, TSXXXXXXX_d, what does it mean by them being a "security" cookie? Does it mean there is no need to secure such cookies by configuring things like httponly/secure flags? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *TS** cookies belong to an F5 load balancer, which also acts as a security device (especially via it's Application Security Module (ASM)).  The cookies and their various uses are described [here](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K6850).

I would interpret the web site describing these cookies as "Security" as meaning they're put in place and used by a security device, as opposed to the web site itself.  They are, in fact, not marked *secure* by default, although it is [possible to add that](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13787?sr=45119777).